# Very weird FileOutputStream behavior on Windows

Tags: java, windows, io

I've checked all the source codes available down to native Windows `CreateFileW` and `WriteFile` calls inside `jdk8u/jdk/src/windows/native/sun/nio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.c`, but I have no idea why these two calls create files with different lenghts:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("x.cfg"));
f.write("hello\n".getBytes());
f.close();
```

and

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("x.txt"));
f.write("hello\n".getBytes());
f.close();
```

I tried different extensions, but it seems that only `.cfg` leads to LF→CRLF conversion...

Looks like it's not Java fault, only Windows.

Comment: Using JDK1.8.0_65 both files have 6 bytes on my system (Windows 7 64bit). May be the content gets altered by a virus scanner?

Comment: I tried with JDK1.8.0_66, Windows 2012R2

Comment: You should check if you have a config.properties file assigned. I am not sure about specifics but here's a link to a usage http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/

Comment: This **is** a Java issue, not a Windows issue. [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) does not convert anything, and [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) doesn't provide a way to specify *text* output. All of the required conversions have to be implemented on top of the Windows API (i.e. the CRT or the JVM).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was OSGi fileinstall service which did the conversion **after** file was written...